# How to send address to geocoder from async php db search

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to get my google maps app to wait for an answer from an ajax call from a db call using php. I know I need to use callbacks but I'm unsure how to implement them in this case since geocoder api is also async.

I tried answer from [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) and [Using gettext with Javascript from PHP via XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477165/using-gettext-with-javascript-from-php-via-xmlhttprequest) but I'm unsure how to edit it to work with my case.

db.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");
(perform query)...
echo json_encode($result_assoc_array);
```

location.php

```
<html>
(html boilerplate)...
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map;
var homeAddress;

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = function() {
    homeAddress = JSON.parse(this.responseText).address; //main field I want is address
};
oReq.open("get", "db.php", true);

oReq.send();

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 15,
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var markers = [];

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': JSON.stringify(homeAddress)
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            markers.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
 (more logic)
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This should give me a map with the marker centered on the address from db but instead I get `Geocode was not successful for the following reason: INVALID_REQUEST` because `homeAddress` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ajax request inside `initMap`, call the geocoder in its callback function when the address is available:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 15,
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var markers = [];

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function() {
      homeAddress = JSON.parse(this.responseText).address; //main field I want is address
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': JSON.stringify(homeAddress)
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          console.log(results);
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.position);
          markers.push(marker);
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    };
    oReq.open("get", "db.php", true);

    oReq.send();    
 (more logic)
```